# LED fails to blink

Tags: micropython, led, raspberry-pi-pico

When I run my code to blink a LED, Thonny runs it well. But on the Raspberry Pi Pico itself the LED is not blinking:

```py
from machine import Pin
from time import sleep

led = Pin(25, Pin.OUT)

while True:
    led.toggle()
    sleep(0.1)
```

I tried resetting the whole board.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you run this code on a Raspberry Pi Pico **W** (with the **W**iFi module) you need to use

```py
led = Pin('LED', Pin.OUT)
```

See [MicroPython Forum Blink onboard LED](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=12832)